# Method for Calculating Autocorrelation Function of an Array

Tags: java, statistics

I'm in need of a real fast autocorrelation algorithm. best would be in java. Have used the Apache Commons PearsonsCorrelation class so far, but it's much too slow. Have also heard of the Wiener Chintschin Theorem trieng this out atm. Im quite interested in the YIN Autocorrelation Algorithm. But haven't found any source implementation yet.

I appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1):

It is quite late but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239096/computing-autocorrelation-with-fft-using-jtransforms-library) in stackoverflow may help you. In accepted answer both brute force and fft are used. **Bruteforce is O(n^2) and FFT is O(n.logn)**