# Computing Autocorrelation with FFT Using JTransforms Library

Tags: java, fft, time-series, correlation

I'm trying to calculate autocorrelation of sample windows in a time series using the code below. I'm applying FFT to that window, then computing magnitudes of real and imaginary parts and setting imaginary part to zero, lastly taking inverse transform of it to obtain autocorrelation:

```
DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(magCnt);
fft.realForward(magFFT);

magFFT[0] = (magFFT[0] * magFFT[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < (magCnt - (magCnt%2)) / 2; i++) {
    magFFT[2*i] = magFFT[2*i] * magFFT[2*i] + magFFT[2*i + 1] * magFFT[2*i + 1];
    magFFT[2*i + 1] = 0.0;
}

if (magCnt % 2 == 0) {
    magFFT[1] = (magFFT[1] * magFFT[1]);
} else {
    magFFT[magCnt/2] = (magFFT[magCnt-1] * magFFT[magCnt-1] + magFFT[1] * magFFT[1]);
}

autocorr = new double[magCnt];
System.arraycopy(magFFT, 0, autocorr, 0, magCnt);
DoubleFFT_1D ifft = new DoubleFFT_1D(magCnt);
ifft.realInverse(autocorr, false);

for (int i = 1; i < autocorr.length; i++)
    autocorr[i] /= autocorr[0];
autocorr[0] = 1.0;
```

The first question is: It is seen that this code maps autocorrelation result to `[0,1]` range, although correlation is supposed to be between -1 and 1. Of course it is easy to map the results to `[-1,1]` range, but I'm not sure if this mapping is correct. How can we interpret the values in the resulting `autocorr` array?

Secondly, with this code I'm geting good results for some periodic series, that is I get higher values for specific autocorrelation indices in accordance with the period of signal. However the result go weird when I apply it to non-periodic signals: all the values in `autocorr` array appear to be very close to 1. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For FFT-based algorithms to work, you must pay careful attention to the definitions, including conventions of the library you are using.  You seem to be confusing the "signal processing" convention for AC and the "statistical" one. And then there is FFT wrapping and zero padding.

Here is a code that's working for the even N case, signal processing convention. It's tested against a brute force wrapped autocorrelation.  The comments show how to convert it to the signal processing convention.  For statistical ac, the mean of the data is subtracted out.  This can be done merely by zeroing out the "0Hz" component of the FFT.  Then the zero'th element of the ac is the variance, and you can normalize by dividing through by this quantity.  The resulting values will fall in -1..1 as you say.

Your code seems to be doing the dividing through, but not ignoring the 0 Hz component of the data.  So it's computing some kind of mashup of the conventions.

```
import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestFFT {

    void print(String msg, double [] x) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        for (double d : x) System.out.println(d);
    }

    /**
     * This is a "wrapped" signal processing-style autocorrelation. 
     * For "true" autocorrelation, the data must be zero padded.  
     */
    public void bruteForceAutoCorrelation(double [] x, double [] ac) {
        Arrays.fill(ac, 0);
        int n = x.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                ac[j] += x[i] * x[(n + i - j) % n];
            }
        }
    }

    private double sqr(double x) {
        return x * x;
    }

    public void fftAutoCorrelation(double [] x, double [] ac) {
        int n = x.length;
        // Assumes n is even.
        DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D(n);
        fft.realForward(x);
        ac[0] = sqr(x[0]);
        // ac[0] = 0;  // For statistical convention, zero out the mean 
        ac[1] = sqr(x[1]);
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i += 2) {
            ac[i] = sqr(x[i]) + sqr(x[i+1]);
            ac[i+1] = 0;
        }
        DoubleFFT_1D ifft = new DoubleFFT_1D(n); 
        ifft.realInverse(ac, true);
        // For statistical convention, normalize by dividing through with variance
        //for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        //    ac[i] /= ac[0];
        //ac[0] = 1;
    }

    void test() {
        double [] data = { 1, -81, 2, -15, 8, 2, -9, 0};
        double [] ac1 = new double [data.length];
        double [] ac2 = new double [data.length];
        bruteForceAutoCorrelation(data, ac1);
        fftAutoCorrelation(data, ac2);
        print("bf", ac1);
        print("fft", ac2);
        double err = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ac1.length; i++)
            err += sqr(ac1[i] - ac2[i]);
        System.out.println("err = " + err);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFFT().test();
    }
}
```

Comment: After I got an answer to another question (http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/finding-peaks-in-an-autocorrelation-function) I thought the same. There is the DC component that needs to be eliminated, but I wasn't sure how to eliminate it. So, do you mean assigning zero to first FFT coefficient will eliminate the DC component? I don't have chance to try it right now.

Comment: Yes.  If you look at the definition of fft, the 0'th component is the mean of the input data.  So zeroing out this component is identical to subtracting out the mean from all the data elements before taking the FFT.  The commented out code above is lightly tested.

Comment: @Gene before You do `ifft.realInverse(ac, true);` You are doing something that looks like calculating power spectrum, but shouldn't the formula look like this : `ac[i] = Math.sqrt(sqr(x[i]) + sqr(x[i+1]));` instead of same thing but without Math.sqrt ?

Comment: @YuriyKravets As I said in the answer, this code is correct for the usual signal processing definition of autocorrelation with wrapping.  If it weren't, it wouldn't produce the same result as the brute force calculation, which essentially implements the definition. If you have a different definition, of course you'll need a different code.