# Optimizing AutoCorrelation for pitch detection

Tags: java, signals, signal-processing

I'm in process of writing a java program that will read in audio from a guitar in 1024 sample chunks, and apply auto-correlation to find pitch. I have code implemented for auto-correlation and it works fine, but for a 1024 sample input it takes 524800 iterations! Is there a way to optimize this as the end goal is to make system detect pitch in almost real-time (right now it's taking 16 milli secs to complete).

I could maybe get away with changing the outer loop to 600 loops as the lowest note E (82Hz ) takes approx 537 samples for a full cycle, but even this turns out to be a hefty 180300 loops overall.

code:

```
    public double[] autoCorrelate(double[] audioIn) 
{

    double sum = 0;
    double[] output = new double[audioIn.length];
    int n = 0;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


    for (n = 0; n < audioIn.length; n++) //shift sample to left after each inner loop
    {

        for (int i = n; i < audioIn.length; i++) 
        {

            sum = sum + (audioIn[i] * audioIn[i - n]); //computes product of signal and n shifted copy

        }

        output[n] = sum;
        sum = 0; //reset for next output value
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = stopTime-startTime;
    System.out.println(totalTime);

    return output;

}
```

Comment: as far as i know, with autocorrelation you will always need O(n^2), so for a 1024 sample it will be (as you wrote): 524800. With  FFT pitch detection is mutch faster

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239096/computing-autocorrelation-with-fft-using-jtransforms-library

Comment: I tried this with fft , but resolution is quite bad for 1024 sample set . 44100/1024 gives a approx 40hz separation of frequencies. Zero padding helps but overall i found it was too finicky using a fft for pitch detection with such limited samples

Comment: You're running up against basic physics here... you're gonna need a bigger boat (i.e faster CPU)